# Binding ColumnDefinition.Width to a DataGridTextColumn does not fire when the usercontrol loads

Tags: binding, datagrid, wpf-controls, datagridtextcolumn

I have a WPF usercontrol that holds a grid, some textboxes, and a `DataGrid`. The textboxes are filers for the data in each column so I'd like them to stay above the relevant column. This is easy unless the user resizes the `DataGridTextColumn`. So, I am Binding the `Grid.ColumnDefinition.Width` to the `DataGridTextColumn.Width`.

It works like a dream... after the first resize. When the form initially opens the textbox is 0 wide. How do I trigger the resize event on the datagrid? Currently I'm binding in the XAML, should I wait until the control is initialized and then do the binding in code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works if you set the width in the constructor for the usercontrol. I can't quite follow the event stack but it seems the width changing event is happening after the bind.